# How do composition and currying interact?

Tags: currying, purescript, function-composition

While doing exercises of chapter 3 of the [Purescript by Example book](https://book.purescript.org/) was puzzled by this:

The exercise is to write an `isInBook :: String -> String -> AddressBook -> Boolean`

```hs
findEntryByName :: String -> String -> AddressBook -> Maybe Entry
findEntryByName first last = head <<< filter
  \entry -> entry.firstName == first && entry.lastName == last

isSomething :: forall a. Maybe a -> Boolean
isSomething a = case a of
  Nothing -> false
  Just _ -> true
```

`AddressBook :: List Entry`, and this does what I want it to do. (on a sidenote, is there a common name for `isSomething`? It seems like a common function to want; a proposition whether something isn't `Nothing`)

But this doesn't compile:

```hs
isInBook = isSomething <<< findEntryByName
```

And after some searching I found that this does:

```hs
isInBook fist last = isSomething <<< findEntryByName first last
```

Why? I found the compile error not terribly helpful, but that may be my inexperience:

```
 Could not match type
                   
    Function String
                   
  with type
         
    Maybe
         

while trying to match type String                       
                           -> List                      
                                { address :: ...        
                                , firstName :: String   
                                , lastName :: String    
                                }                       
                              -> Maybe                  
                                   { address :: ...     
                                   , firstName :: String
                                   , lastName :: String 
                                   }                    
  with type Maybe t1
while checking that expression findEntryByName
  has type t0 -> Maybe t1
in value declaration isInBook

where t0 is an unknown type
      t1 is an unknown type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the error message that you got wasn't particularly helpful. I'll try to break down why it happens.

Basically it comes down to the type of `<<<`, which in the context of functions is:

```
(<<<) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

So when you do `isInBook = isSomething <<< findEntryByName`, since `isSomething` has type `Maybe a -> Boolean`, we must have that `b` in the above "generic" type signature is `Maybe a` and `c` is `Boolean`. But the type of `findEntryByName` is `String -> String -> AddressBook -> Maybe Entry`, which would mean that `a` has to be `String` and `b` has to be the function type `String -> AddressBook -> Maybe Entry`. [Recall here that functions in Purescript are curried, so `a -> b -> c` means precisely `a -> (b -> c)`.] We have inferred `b` to be 2 completely different things, and that is exactly what your error message is complaining about.

Basically `<<<` only really works well with functions of one argument. This is what your corrected version does: `findEntryByName first last` is a function of type `AddressBook -> Maybe Entry`, which composes perfectly with `isSomething :: Maybe a -> Boolean`.

You can use it with functions of more than one argument - after all, due to currying all functions in Purescript strictly speaking taking one argument - but as you saw with `findEntryByName`, trying to compose something with a function of more than one argument means that your next function itself has to take a function as argument.

If the repetition of `first` and `last` in the correct expression, `isInBook first last = isSomething <<< findEntryByName first last`, bothers you, then you can if you want eta-reduce to get rid of `last`:

```
isInBook first = \last -> isSomething <<< findEntryByName first last
               = (isSomething <<< _) <<< (findEntryByName first)
```

and then do similar with `first` to make it fully point-free. But the final expression will be fairly unreadable, and even the above looks much worse to me than the original. Fewer explicit arguments isn't always better.

Oh, and your `isSomething` is indeed in the standard libraries, as [isJust](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-maybe/6.0.0/docs/Data.Maybe#v:isJust). It's not actually as commonly useful as you seem to think, because most of the time when you have a `Just` value you want to actually extract the underlying value and do something with it, rather than throw information away with a Boolean `True`. But well sometimes that is all you want, as in your case, and for those cases the function exists.